# Spring Data Jpa custom repository no property found

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a repository that has a method which doesn't fit the usual `JpaRepository` with `@Query` annotations.

I've created a custom repository interface:

```
public interface CustomVoteRepository {

  List<VoteCountResult> countVotesForSession();
}
```

And the implementation:

```
@Repository
public class CustomVoteRepositoryImp implements CustomVoteRepository {

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public CustomVoteRepositoryImp(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public List<VoteCountResult> countVotesForSession() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT video_id, COUNT(votes.id) FROM votes WHERE session_id=2 GROUP BY video_id",
        new CustomRowMapper());
  }
}
```

However, this gives me this error:

`No property countVotesForSession found for type Vote!`

I don't understand why it's trying to map a property on the Vote class. I understand it does this for the "auto-generated" method names, but this is supposed to be a custom one.

I've come across this article: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/ which explains what I'm doing, and yet it's trying to map a property of the model for a custom repository.

I'm sure I missed something stupid.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's the VoteCountResult dto:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VoteCountResult {

  private String count;
  private String title;
  private String url;
}
```

Comment: Where's `VoteCountResult`?

Comment: @TheHeadRush I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your custom method name to `votesForSessionCount` ? I think this way you won't face with method name conflict.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of names indeed, no luck. Just tried your suggestion and still getting  `No property votesForSessionCount found for type Vote!`